How to remediate a VLCM cluster using pyVim or pyVmomi
Hello fellow community members, Currently I'm manually remediating vLCM clusters. I want to do it automatic once install filter driver.
Is there any API call or method available in pyVim or pyVmomi to automate this task. I have searched but couldn't successful. Thank you.
